# Captive mode doesn't work

Tags: stellar-core

```
stellar-core: 17.3.1-666.97aeb24.focal 
stellar-horizon: 2.7.0-133
```

https://developers.stellar.org/docs/run-api-server/migrating/

I'm use private network with 3 nodes and try migrate.

If I disable captive-core, it's works. When I try enable, I  seeing message "Joing SCP", but he can't join to network.

```
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="Bucket: Bucket-apply: 84913 entries in 8.97MB/8.97MB in 6/21 files (99%)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Applying buckets 99%. Currently on level 6" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Applying buckets 99%. Currently on level 5" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Applying buckets 99%. Currently on level 4" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Applying buckets 99%. Currently on level 3" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Applying buckets 99%. Currently on level 2" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Applying buckets 99%. Currently on level 1" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Applying buckets 99%. Currently on level 0" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.238Z" level=info msg="History: ApplyBuckets : done, restarting merges" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.246Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Succeeded: download-verify-apply-buckets" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.246Z" level=info msg="History: Downloading, unzipping and applying transactions for checkpoint 3213311" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.246Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Download & apply checkpoints: num checkpoints left to apply:1 (0% done)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.496Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Download & apply checkpoints: num checkpoints left to apply:0 (100% done)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.496Z" level=info msg="History: Catching up to ledger 3213279: Succeeded: catchup-seq" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.496Z" level=info msg="History: Catchup finished" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.496Z" level=info msg="default: *" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.496Z" level=info msg="default: * Catchup finished." pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.496Z" level=info msg="default: *" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.496Z" level=info msg="Ledger: Skipping application start up" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:38.496Z" level=info msg="Overlay: Binding to endpoint 0.0.0.0:11625" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:40.548Z" level=info msg="Overlay: Connected to 10.112.131.89:11625" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:40.550Z" level=info msg="Overlay: Connected to 10.112.131.92:11625" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:40.553Z" level=info msg="Overlay: Connected to 10.112.131.93:11625" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:47.660Z" level=info msg="History: Downloading ledger checkpoint ledger-0000003f.xdr.gz from archive sdf_node_1" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:47.672Z" level=info msg="History: Local ledger header 1 matches archive sdf_node_1" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:47.672Z" level=info msg="History: Downloading ledger checkpoint ledger-0000003f.xdr.gz from archive sdf_node_2" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:47.681Z" level=info msg="History: Local ledger header 1 matches archive sdf_node_2" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:47.681Z" level=info msg="History: Downloading ledger checkpoint ledger-0000003f.xdr.gz from archive sdf_node_3" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:47.692Z" level=info msg="History: Local ledger header 1 matches archive sdf_node_3" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:57.625Z" level=info msg="default: Performing maintenance" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:53:57.625Z" level=info msg="History: Trimming history <= ledger 3213215 (rmin=4294967295, qmin=3213279, lmin=3213215)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:54:27.629Z" level=info msg="default: Performing maintenance" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:54:27.629Z" level=info msg="History: Trimming history <= ledger 3213215 (rmin=4294967295, qmin=3213279, lmin=3213215)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:54:57.629Z" level=info msg="default: Performing maintenance" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:54:57.629Z" level=info msg="History: Trimming history <= ledger 3213215 (rmin=4294967295, qmin=3213279, lmin=3213215)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:55:27.630Z" level=info msg="default: Performing maintenance" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:55:27.630Z" level=info msg="History: Trimming history <= ledger 3213215 (rmin=4294967295, qmin=3213279, lmin=3213215)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:55:57.630Z" level=info msg="default: Performing maintenance" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:55:57.630Z" level=info msg="History: Trimming history <= ledger 3213215 (rmin=4294967295, qmin=3213279, lmin=3213215)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:56:27.630Z" level=info msg="default: Performing maintenance" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:56:27.630Z" level=info msg="History: Trimming history <= ledger 3213215 (rmin=4294967295, qmin=3213279, lmin=3213215)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:56:57.631Z" level=info msg="default: Performing maintenance" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:56:57.631Z" level=info msg="History: Trimming history <= ledger 3213215 (rmin=4294967295, qmin=3213279, lmin=3213215)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:57:27.631Z" level=info msg="default: Performing maintenance" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
time="2021-08-22T15:57:27.631Z" level=info msg="History: Trimming history <= ledger 3213215 (rmin=4294967295, qmin=3213279, lmin=3213215)" pid=1 service=ingest subservice=stellar-core
```

Comment: Can you add more information on setup? Like: you have N validators running and you try to start a new captive core node with some configuration (captive-core is getting configured by Horizon also, so you'll need to share the Horizon configuration as well)

Comment: my mistake. 
I set incorrect public keys in stellar-captive-core.toml. I found when added next full validator.

Now captive core working correctly